# How do I import a Half-Life save into Half-Life: Source?

Tags: source-engine, half-life, half-life-series

I started playing Half-Life on my computer a few weeks ago when I bought Half-Life: Complete. I didn't realize that Half-Life: Source was an improved remove of Half-Life and I want to switch.

Can I import my Half-Life save file into Half-Life: Source?

Comment: Have you tried copying your savegame over?

Comment: No; do you think they it would be compatible?

Comment: It's not really improved over gldsrc Half Life. Just that enemies ragdoll so you can blow them up with your crowbar anymore, it's kind of worse.

Comment: Honestly, you're probably better off waiting for [Black Mesa Source](http://www.blackmesasource.com)'s Steam release or at least the "final" version of the free version (iirc it's missing the end of the game at this point).

Answer (score 5):

No - unfortunately not. The Gold SRC engine used in Half Life and the Source engine used in Half Life: Source are completely different engines with no save game compatibility.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be possible to have a program that converts between the two formats, the issue is the complexity if the formats are very different in design.